# Accessing Picasa from Android - Google Data APIs

Tags: android, google-api, picasa, google-api-java-client

it seems that I'm not the first one, but I don't find anything that helps. I'm new to Android and would like to develop a real simple photo sharing app (three tabs: camera, gallery and upload to Picasa) to start off. Unfortunately the [Google Data APIs for Java](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/), don't run on Android and I didn't find a good tutorial for the newer [Google Data API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/). I also couldn't get the [Android Picasa sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/picasa-atom-android-sample/instructions.html) to run: Eclipse complains about a buildpath error, but doesn't show what exactly is wrong.

I'm looking for an easy tutorial how to use Picasa with Android. Anyone has some kind of "middleware classes" between the old and the new API which one can use. How do I fix the buildpatj problem to run the sample or how in general can I import external JARs to my Android project.

Comment: thanks for including the links.

Comment: I got rid of the buildpath error in eclipse simply by restarting eclipse. The app starts but only shows a blank screen. Debugging step-by-step reveals an IllegealStateException in line 185. In line 127 the if-condition is wrong and no SendData object is created. In the settings it says "Sync is OFF" beneath Google Account. Is that usual using the AVD or are my settings wrong?

Comment: Here are the docs / links that I used to get my Android app working with Picasa:
<br />
http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html
<br />
http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/picasa-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting the problem, Daniel.  I actually [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/detail?r=db6652abeaabd7aa390fbdd5b4a39ea013212088&repo=samples#) this bug recently on 9/13/2010.  Please try the sample again and let me know if you encounter any problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. That makes sense. The error message of the IllegalStateException said that you can't start the activity in the main thread. I used the other Android example and switched to ClientLogin for my purpose, which works ok, since I couldn't set-up a Google Account in Android 2.1 ... or is there any other way?

Comment: @Yaniv Inbar I am trying to run example called "PicasaAtomAndroidSample" and getting this error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleTransport` . Can you help me out?